# XAML WrapPanel inside TreeView

Tags: xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView displaying items through a Hierarchical Data Template. Now I want to display two properties of an object in the TreeView, as in:

```
Object1 Name                 Object1 Src
  Object2 Name               Object2 Src
    Object3 Name             Object3 Src
```

How can I format the output, so that the Src is always aligned on the right side of the TreeViewItem?

Answer (score 0):

The TreeViewItem is not streched to full width by default. You can do this by overriding the default style.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Should I then be able to do it like this?
`<HierarchicalDataTemplate><WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/><TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SrcFile.Name" HorizontalAlignment="Right" /></WrapPanel>`